# BAT and HTA with VBS

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, adb, stdout, hta

I have a program called kindlesuite (kfsowi.com) that is basically an HTA interface to a bunch of BAT's. What I want to do is eliminate the cmd windows and display the output inside the HTA in a div. It doesn't have to be pretty, just functional. I'd be happy with saving the output to a .txt and displaying that if it could be in (fairly) real-time. I also need to make the dig auto scroll, but I'll cross that bridge when I get there (probably JavaScript) 
       Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I should mention that i have searched this on google, but im really trying to avoid a script that is a mile long because i have ~20 BAT's

Comment: Well that is what functions are for, doing the sme thing to different thingsover and over. 1/ You can have it hidden. You will need to pipe and then read the file. `WshShell.Run "cmd /k batfile.bat>output.txt", 0, false`. 2/ You can easily get the output but not hidden. `Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
:Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("cmd /c dir&exit")
:Do While oExec.Status = 0
 :WScript.Sleep 100
:Loop
:WScript.Echo "Yes" & oExec.stdout.readall`

Comment: Ah i feel dumb for not thinking of option one. I hadnt really considered a txt file for the output until i was typing up the question. Thank you very much

Comment: @Noodles: `Exec` doesn't hide the command prompt.

Comment: He mentioned that. im going to try the first method and either use the txt in a Js function, or use an htm instead of txt and use a frame then use Js for an autoscroll function (possibly)

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this ? [[HTA] UnicodeSimulDOS](http://pastebin.com/i2jwSEZ1)